# WP Rest API: Can't seem to get embedded data from the post object

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-rest-api

I am working with the WORDPRESS REST API and Wordpress version 4.8 for an internal network page at a local office.  We have permalinks disabled (security reasons) and thus I am accessing the posts object like so:

```
https://url/blogs/usernamehere/?rest_route=/wp/v2/posts/12345
```

I am able to do a GET request and can get the posts data into my view template with no issues. However, I can't seem to figure out how to consume additional content in the post object . I have followed the documentation and tried to do:

```
https://url/blogs/usernamehere/?rest_route=/wp/v2/posts/12345?_embed=true
```

But, I get a STATUS 404 .

**How would I correctly apply the embed function in the URL so I can get the additional data associated with the post?**

Comment: Could you post the JSON response from your first request as an edit to your question?

Comment: Unfortunatley, due to restricted info in the response, I can't. But, I'll try to replicate publicly and see if I run into the same issue.

Answer (score 2):

Pass the `_embed` global parameter without a value, per the [documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/using-the-rest-api/global-parameters/#_embed).

Comment: I did: `https://url/blogs/usernamehere/?rest_route=/wp/v2/posts/12345?_embed` and still got 404 status. Am I doing this right?

Comment: Well it's not the typical WP REST route format. Did you customize your own route? Otherwise try `https://yoururl/wp-json/wp/v2/posts/1234‌​5?_embed`

Comment: @redshift what came of this?

Comment: It turned out that the official WP REST API docs were wrong. You have to append `&` instead of `?` to the URL like so: https://url/blogs/usernamehere/?rest_route=/wp/v2/posts&_embed

Comment: You should answer your own question then and mark it answered.

Comment: @redshift The docs aren't wrong, they just assume that _embed is the first query parameter you are passing.   Any time you are passing query parameters the first one is preceded by a ? and subsequent parameters are preceded by an ampersand.  e.g.  getcookies.com?type=chocolatechip  and getcookies.com?number=2&type=chocolatechip

Comment: this will work: https://url/blogs/usernamehere/?_embed=true&rest_route=/wp/v2/posts/12345

Answer (score 0):

you should do this:

```
https://url/blogs/usernamehere/?_embed=true&rest_route=/wp/v2/posts/12345
```

Basically you add `_embed=true` at before other parameters and after `&` add other parameters.